# Confused by this - getting error "this.myfuntion() is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Background: I am trying to edit a zen cart horizontal pop out menu to make the popout open inline within the menu. The problem I am having is that I am struggling to get my head around the javascript/jquery that came with it.

Without posting the whole thing the structure of the code is something like this:

```
(declare some vars)

//some functions like this:
function funcname(obj) {
//do something
}

//then one big master function like this:
function bigfunc(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5) {

//declare some vars based on this
this.varname1=varname1;
this.varname2=varname2;

//declare some functions inside the big function
this.innerfunc1= function() {
//do stuff
}

this.innerfunc2= function() {
//do stuff
}

}//end of big function

//then goes on to declare init function

function initfunc(){
//this creates new bigfunc(arg1 arg2 arg3...) for each main menu item
}

//finally calls init function with
window.onload = initfunc();
```

Now on to my confusion -

1) firstly for clarification, am I correct in thinking based on all the this's floating about in bigfunc() and the fact that it is called with new bigfunc() that this is creating an object?

2)My current problem is with one of the functions inside bigfunc() which looks like this:

```
this.slideChildMenu = function() {
        var divref = this.children[0].div;
        var ulref = this.children[0].ul;
        var maxwidth = this.children[0].width;
        var nextWidth;
        if (this.isMouseOnMe  || this.isMouseOnChild()) {
            nextWidth = divref.offsetWidth + slideSpeed_out;
            if (nextWidth >= maxwidth) {
                this.finishOpeningChild(divref, ulref, maxwidth);
            } else {
                ulref.style.left = nextWidth - maxwidth + "px";
                divref.style.width = nextWidth + "px";
                setTimeout("slideChildMenu('" + this.getId() + "')", slideTimeout_out);
            }
        }
```

Now my plan is to alter this to use jquery show to open the element so I tried this:

```
this.slideChildMenu = function() {
        var divref = this.children[0].div;
        var ulref = this.children[0].ul;
        if (this.isMouseOnMe  || this.isMouseOnChild()) {
            $(divref).show(function(){
                    this.finishOpeningChild(divref, ulref);
                });
            }
        }
```

But I am getting this-> TypeError: this.finishOpeningChild is not a function

Now, there is a lot of other stuff going on in this js so I wouldnt dream of asking someone on here to do my work for me, but I am hoping that if someone can explain to me why this function is not a function I may be able to work the rest out.

NOTE: I thought this was to do with the scope of "this" but the value of this appears to be exactly the same in both versions of the code.

I know this is a long one but your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` in a function is called the "context" in which the function runs. In general, whenever you pass a callback function as an argument (as you do with `$(divref).show(function() {...})`), the function can run the callback in whatever context it wants. In this case, the jQuery `show` function chooses to run its callback in the context of the element being animated.

However, you want access to the value of `this` at the time the anonymous callback function is *defined*, rather than when it is run. The solution here is to store the outer value of `this` in a variable (traditionally called `self`) which is included in the scope of the newly-defined function:

```
this.slideChildMenu = function() {
    //...
    var self = this;
    $(divref).show(function(){
        self.finishOpeningChild(divref, ulref);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed - no more error... still doesnt work but I think I have a chance of fixing it now. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice suggestion.  I have done this when its necessary since lets you capture the current scope before it changes. +1!

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that the jQuery selector has changed the scope of `this`.

In your example `$(this);` would refer to object being animated per jQuery api docs:

> If supplied, the callback is fired once the animation is complete. This can be useful for stringing different animations together in sequence. The callback is not sent any arguments, but **this is set to the DOM element being animated**. If multiple elements are animated, it is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.

If the object in question is instantiated you can call it with dot notation without using `this` like `bigFunc.finishOpeningChild(divref, ulref);`

Comment: thank you for the suggestion - the object has been called at this point (as this function is within the object) but changing as suggested gives the error:  TypeError: bigfunc.finishOpeningChild is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You're probably a little confused about scope, it's not always easy keeping track, but doing something more like this:

```
var site = {
    init: function(elm) {
        self=site;
        self.master.funcname2(self.varname1, elm); //call function in master
    },
    funcname: function(obj) {
        //do something
    },
    varname1: 'some string',
    varname2: 3+4,
    master: function() {
        this.varname3 = sin(30);
        this.funcname2 = function(stuff, element) {
            site.funcname(element); //call function in 'site'
            var sinus = site.master.varname3; //get variable
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    var elm = document.getElementById('elementID');
    site.init(elm); //call init function
}
```

usually makes it a little easier to keep track.

Comment: Thank you for the tip - and I certainly wouldnt have written it like this myself but it is what it is and I dont have time to rewrite the whole thing, so I need a quick and dirty fix.